# In DRF, how to get dictionary format in JSON response rather than List of dcitionaries

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to get dictionary format in JSON response rather than List of dictionaries. Right now am getting response like list of dictionaries and I want to get response without list.

#Response I get for example

```
[
    {
        "id": 40,
        "full_name": "Don Ser 1",
        "email": "Donny@sfds.com",
        "phone": 12345,
        "address_line_1": "sdsdsdsd",
        "address_line_2": "dsdsdsd",
   
    },
    {
        "id": 41,
        "full_name": "Don Ser 2",
        "email": "Donny@sfds.com",
        "phone": 121356456,
        "address_line_1": "sdsdsdsd",
        "address_line_2": "dsdsdsd",
    
    }
]
```

#Response I Like to get is without List.

```
[
    {
        "id": 40,
        "full_name": "Don Ser 1",
        "email": "Donny@sfds.com",
        "phone": 12345,
        "address_line_1": "sdsdsdsd",
        "address_line_2": "dsdsdsd",
     
    },
    {
        "id": 41,
        "full_name": "Don Ser 2",
        "email": "Donny@sfds.com",
        "phone": 121356456,
        "address_line_1": "sdsdsdsd",
        "address_line_2": "dsdsdsd",
  
    }
}
```

How do I achieve this?
Additionally I like to know why it returned it in List rather than dictionary?

Comment: If you return a dict in your response you will get a dict.  What and how are you returning it.  Also, if using a ViewSet, you can enable pagination and you will get the next/previous/count/results dictionary.

Comment: Im actually passing a list of objects in it, and passing `many=True`, aybe because of that its returning list of dicts

Comment: It is giving you a list because you gave it a list of objects to return.  You need to be more specific about what you wan here.  *Add your view code*, add your exact expected response format (don't just say `dict`!).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return a dict you must define a structure, e.g.

```
{'results': [
 {
        "id": 40,
        "full_name": "Don Ser 1",
        "email": "Donny@sfds.com",
        "phone": 12345,
        "address_line_1": "sdsdsdsd",
        "address_line_2": "dsdsdsd",
     
    },
    {
        "id": 41,
        "full_name": "Don Ser 2",
        "email": "Donny@sfds.com",
        "phone": 121356456,
        "address_line_1": "sdsdsdsd",
        "address_line_2": "dsdsdsd",
  
    }
]}
```

But just return a dict without a key is not possible.

Comment: Hey My doubt is that why its giving List of dicts?, instead of whole dict?

Answer (score 1):

If you are returning your response in `DRF` with `serializer.data` the simplest way to achieve that is:

```
return Response(serializer.data[0], status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

If you want to include the whole dictionary in another dictionary you'd have to give it a key so it would something like this:

```
return Response({"results":serializer.data[0]}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Otherwise if you are using it on a simple item you can just specify it the way you want i.e. :

```
serializer = Serializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    device = serializer.save()
    return Response({"pk": device.id}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: serializer.data[0], what does this data[0] do here?

Comment: Since `serializer.data` returns your serializer inside a list, it just gets the first element of that list therefore removing the brackets.

Comment: This only returns the first item in the data, which doesn't seem to be desired when the example returns multiple.

Comment: all results from `serializer` are returned as a one item array therefore it returns the desired output. check the example again and see how this works